# Elijah and the dying man

Tags: sources-mekorot, tzedakah-charity, story-identification, eliyahu-hanavi

I remember reading long ago that the prophet Elijah sometimes will appear to a dying man pretending to be a beggar asking charity, to give the man one last chance of doing an act of tzedakah.  Is this correct and what is the reference?

Comment: At least the bit about Tzedakah having the ability to reverse a decree of death is an explicit passuk (Mishlei 10:2)

Comment: Perhaps you’re thinking of Pirkei d’Rebbi Eliezer 33:2, that we learn from Eliyahu that Tzedakah has the power to revive the dead?

Comment: No, it was as precise as I described.

Answer (score 1):

Did you read a somewhat similar story which appears in Louis Ginzberg's [The Legends of the Jews](https://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/loj/index.htm), vol. 4 ch. 7 ?

> There were two brothers, one of them rich and miserly, the other poor
>   and kind-hearted. **Elijah, in the garb of an old beggar, approached the
>   rich man, and asked him for alms**. Repulsed by him, he turned to the
>   poor brother, who received him kindly, and shared his meagre supper
>   with him. On bidding farewell to him and his equally hospitable wife,
>   Elijah said: "May God reward you! The first thing you undertake shall
>   be blessed, and shall take no end until you yourselves cry out
>   Enough!" Presently the poor man began to count the few pennies he had,
>   to convince himself that they sufficed to purchase bread for his next
>   meal. But the few became many, and he counted and counted, and still
>   their number increased. He counted a whole day, and the following
>   night, until he was exhausted, and had to cry out Enough! And, indeed,
>   it was enough, for he had become a very wealthy man.
>
> His brother was not a little astonished to see the fortunate change in
>   his kinsman's circumstances, and when he heard how it had come about,
>   he determined, if the opportunity should present itself again, to show
>   his most amiable side to the old beggar with the miraculous power of
>   blessing. He had not long to wait. A few days later he saw the old man
>   pass by. He hastened to accost him, and, excusing himself for his
>   unfriendliness at their former meeting, begged him to come into his
>   house. All that the larder afforded was put before Elijah, who
>   pretended to eat of the dainties. At his departure, he pronounced a
>   blessing upon his hosts: "May the first thing you do have no end,
>   until it is enough." The mistress of the house thereupon said to her
>   husband: "That we may count gold upon gold undisturbed, let us first
>   attend to our most urgent physical needs." **So they did and they had
>   to continue to do it until life was extinct.**

Comment: The source is given ([here](https://archive.org/details/legendsofjews06ginz/page/329) footnote 64) as "the Jewish version of a widespread legend among European nations." In any case this has Elijah pretending to be a beggar, but I'm not sure it matches the aspect of being a last chance to give charity before dying

Comment: I agree it is not the same - but sometimes memories from long ago can be distorted so I thought it might be close enough to be the story the OP was looking for

Comment: I remember distinctly the words "to give the man one last chance of doing an act of charity", but maybe it's the author I read who extrapolated from Ginzberg. So that may well be it.  Thanks.